# Java Spring: ManytoOne EmbeddedId in child class with additional Id - getting null error on child specific PK

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was able to get this ManyToOne relationship with a composite pk working for GET requests but I am having issues with saving new entries.

I have a parent entity with an embedded id.

```
@Embeddable
public class AnnualServiceHistoryPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "year", columnDefinition = "int(4)")
    Integer year;
    @Column(name = "month", columnDefinition = "char(3)")
    String month;
    @Column(name = "route", columnDefinition = "varchar(32)")
    String route;
```

This is placed in the parent entity:

```
@Entity(name = "AnnualServiceHistory")
@Table(name = "annual_service_history")
public class AnnualServiceHistory extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable 
{ 
@EmbeddedId
AnnualServiceHistoryPK annualServiceHistoryPK;

... other variables

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "annualServiceHistory", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<AnnualServiceHistoryNonMachine> annualServiceHistoryNonMachineList;
```

I have the child entity which maps the embedded id from the parent and adds and additional local PK.

```
public class AnnualServiceHistoryNonMachine extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @MapsId
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "year", referencedColumnName = "year")
    @JoinColumn(name = "month", referencedColumnName = "month")
    @JoinColumn(name = "route", referencedColumnName = "route")
    private AnnualServiceHistory annualServiceHistory;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "toy_inventory", referencedColumnName = "id")
    ToyInventory toyInventory;

... other variables
```

My issue is, when I save the parent with a list of children for some reason during the cascading processes, when it is generating the child key it is only creating the key from the MapsId parts and complains that the toyInventory key is null. I'm not sure why it loses this ID because prior to performing the repository save the child class has the toyInventory key in the object.

This is the error I am receiving:
"java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'toy_inventory' cannot be null"

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. - https://medium.com/@bhagyajayashani/composite-key-handling-using-idclass-annotation-in-spring-boot-java-26f40bbd38a2

Changed from using @embeddedId to using @classId. Then created a separate join object, and created join based off individual variables not the embeddedId.

```
@Embeddable
public class AnnualServiceHistoryPK implements Serializable {

    Integer year;
    String month;
    String route;

    public AnnualServiceHistoryPK() {
    }
```

```
@Entity(name = "AnnualServiceHistory")
@Table(name = "annual_service_history")
@IdClass(AnnualServiceHistoryPK.class)
public class AnnualServiceHistory extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "year", columnDefinition = "int(4)")
    Integer year;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "month", columnDefinition = "char(3)")
    String month;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "route", columnDefinition = "varchar(32)")
    String route;

... other variables ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "annualServiceHistory", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<AnnualServiceHistoryNonMachine> annualServiceHistoryNonMachineList;
```

```
@Embeddable
public class AnnualServiceHistoryNonMachinePK implements Serializable {

    Integer year;
    String month;
    String route;
    ToyInventory toyInventory;

    public AnnualServiceHistoryNonMachinePK() {
    }
```

```
@Entity(name = "AnnualServiceHistoryNonMachine")
@Table(name = "annual_service_history_non_machine")
@IdClass(AnnualServiceHistoryNonMachinePK.class)
public class AnnualServiceHistoryNonMachine extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "year", columnDefinition = "int(4)")
    Integer year;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "month", columnDefinition = "char(3)")
    String month;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "route", columnDefinition = "varchar(32)")
    String route;

... other variables ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "year", referencedColumnName = "year", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "month", referencedColumnName = "month", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "route", referencedColumnName = "route", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    @JsonIgnore
    private AnnualServiceHistory annualServiceHistory;
```